# How to check for a pagetemplate before include Ajax functionality?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Here's what I'm trying to do:

i have a function in my functions.php which loads a class that implements AJAX functionality.

```
            $ajaxClass = '\\Theme\\Ajax\\' . $name;
            new $ajaxClass;
```

And this is where I get stuck. I try to verify the template name with get_page_template() now, but that doesn't work. Loading the whole thing via a hook didn't work either. Either the associated JS is not loaded or I get a "Bad Request" back when executing the AJAX call.

Without the check on the template name everything works fine.

Can someone please give me a tip?

Comment: What hook(s) did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earliest hook I'd recommend for determining the page template is [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/). From this hook, you can use conditional functions to determine what the request is for, and whether to load your AJAX class (untested):

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', static function () {

    // Conditionally initialize the AJAX class.
    if ( 'uses-ajax.php' !== get_page_template() ) {
        return;
    }

    $name = ''; // define

    $ajaxClass = '\\Theme\\Ajax\\' . $name;
    new $ajaxClass;
} );
```